# Expo Location watchHeadingAsync not working on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am writing an app that requires me to track the heading of the user's device. Everything works fine on iOS, but on Android the heading is very unstable and flickers between 2 values very often:

```
Log output:
angle: 17.43
angle: 358.7
angle: 17.43
angle: 358.7
```

Here is my code:

```
    onVidLoad(){
        Location.watchHeadingAsync(this.onHeadingUpdate).then((v) => {
            this.ang_listener = v;
        });
    }

    onHeadingUpdate = (h) => {
        var angle = h.trueHeading;
        angle -= 180;
        angle *= -1;
        angle += 180;

        console.log("angle:", angle);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I am using Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync every time the app starts, so the problem isn't that I don't have the correct permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue with Location.watchHeadingAsync on Android. The heading works to some extent but is very unstable and tends to jump around a lot.

As an alternative, I suggest using DeviceMotion to get the device's heading on Android devices.

### For Android:

You can use DeviceMotion from expo-sensors to get more reliable heading data. Below is an example code snippet:

```
import { DeviceMotion } from 'expo-sensors';
// ...
const [deviceMotionHeading, setDeviceMotionHeading] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  let deviceMotionSubscription = DeviceMotion.addListener(({ rotation }) => {
    // Extract rotation data
    const { alpha } = rotation;

    // Calculate heading
    let calculatedHeading = 360 - (alpha * 180 / Math.PI);
    if (calculatedHeading < 0) {
      calculatedHeading += 360;
    }
    if (calculatedHeading > 360) {
      calculatedHeading -= 360;
    }

    setDeviceMotionHeading(calculatedHeading);
  });

  return () => {
    deviceMotionSubscription && deviceMotionSubscription.remove();
  };
}, []);
```

### For iOS:

Location.watchHeadingAsync works reliably on iOS. Here's an example:

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
// ...
const [locationHeading, setLocationHeading] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
      return;
    }

    let locationSubscription = await Location.watchHeadingAsync((locationHeading) => {
      setLocationHeading(locationHeading.trueHeading);
    });

    return () => {
      locationSubscription && locationSubscription.remove();
    };
  })();
}, []);
```

You can adjust the update interval to smoothen the heading updates like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  DeviceMotion.setUpdateInterval(16); // Added this line
  let deviceMotionSubscription = DeviceMotion.addListener(({ rotation }) => {
    // Extract rotation data
    const { alpha } = rotation;
```

For 16 milliseconds, which is 0.016 seconds:

Frequency (in Hz) = 1 / (Time interval in seconds)

Frequency (in Hz) = 1 / 0.016 ≈ 62.5 Hz

You might also want to set a fixed number of decimal places to reduce the frequency of re-renders, making your UI more performant. For example, you can round the heading to one decimal place as follows:

```
setDeviceMotionHeading(calculatedHeading.toFixed(1));
```